# Why does this regex fail?

Tags: java, regex

I have a PCL file and open it with Notepad ++ to view the source code (with PCL Viewer I see the final results but I need to view the source also).

[image]

Please see Lab Number and the rest of the characters. **I am able** to extract Lab Number and its code with this regex:

```
private static String PATTERN_LABNUMBER = "Lab Number[\\W\\D]*(\\d*)";
```

and it gives me:

```
0092616281
```

I now want to extract Date Reported and I use this regex (after a lot of other tries):

```
private static String PATTERN_DATE_REPORTED =
        "Date Reported[\\W\\D]*(\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d \\d\\d:\\d\\d)";
```

but it does NOT find it in the PCL file.

I've also tried with:

```
private static String PATTERN_DATE_REPORTED =
        "Date Reported[\\W\\D]*([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})";
```

but the same not found result...
Do you see where I am missing something in this last regex?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**:

I use this java code to extract Lab number and Date Reported:

```
 public String extractWithRegEx(String regextype, String input) {
        String matchedString = null;

        if (regextype != null && input != null) {
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regextype).matcher(input);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Matcher found for regextype "+regextype);
                matchedString = matcher.group(0);
                if (matcher.groupCount() > 0) {
                    matchedString = matcher.group(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return matchedString;
    }
```

Comment: The image you posted and your question is not making any sense...

Comment: Be careful when using the negated shorthands inside square brackets. `[\\W\\D]` is **not** the same as `[^\\w\\d]`. The latter will match any character that is not an alphanumeric or digit. So it will match `*` or `(`, but not `x` or `8`. The former, however, will match any character that is either not an alphanumeric, or is not a digit. Because a letter is not a digit, `[\\W\\D]` **will** match any letter, dispite the use of `\\W`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to accomplish what you want..

```
       Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("Date Reported.*(\\d{2}/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2})$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        String st = "date dfdsfsd fgfd gdfgfdgdf gdfgdfg gdfgdf 3232/22/2010 23:34\n"+
        "dsadsadasDate Reported gdfgfd gdfgfdgdf gdfgdfg gdfgdf 3232/22/2010 23:34";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: +1, except I don't see why you need the lookahead, `(?=Date Reported.*)`.  Why not match it straight, like the OP did?

Comment: especially , I have tried not to use group, but I could not succeed.. Look ahead is unnecessary..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pattern.MULTILINE was the key!!!! If I put this, it's working with my initial regex also!